# Jasper report sort null/empty values last

Tags: jasper-reports

i have in report group and subgroup and need to sort them alphabetically but i want sort null or empty values as last. Is there option or some work around to made it? Thanks Pavel

Comment: What *DB* are you using (if you are using jdbc datasource)?

Comment: @AlexK I use bean data source from java

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this result with help of sorting options and additional variable.

The steps:

- Add the variable for determine if the field is empty or null. For example, with help of [guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) the expression for this variable can be like this (see [Strings.isNullOrEmpty(String) method](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#isNullOrEmpty%28java.lang.String%29))

```xml
<variable name="isNull" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[Strings.isNullOrEmpty($F{fieldName})]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

- Add two sorting instructions - for sorting by our new variable (goes first) and for sorting by field (goes second)

```xml
<sortField name="isNull" order="Ascending" type="Variable"/>
<sortField name="fieldName"/>
```

---

The full working sample. The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ...>
    <import value="com.google.common.base.*"/>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="city" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <sortField name="isNull" order="Ascending" type="Variable"/>
    <sortField name="city"/>
<variable name="isNull" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[Strings.isNullOrEmpty($F{city})]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{city}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The Java code for testing:

```java
private void testReport() throws JRException {
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, getDataSource());

    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, outputFileName);
}

private JRDataSource getDataSource() {
    Collection<Address> list = new ArrayList<Address>();

    list.add(new Address(1, "Dallas"));

    list.add(new Address(2, "Dallas"));

    list.add(new Address(3, "Dallas"));

    list.add(new Address(5, null));

    list.add(new Address(4, ""));

    list.add(new Address(6, "Boston"));

    list.add(new Address(7, "Chicago"));

    list.add(new Address(8, "Dallas"));

    list.add(new Address(9, ""));

    list.add(new Address(10, null));

    list.add(new Address(11, null));

    return new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list);
}
```

In this sample the ***Address*** is a simple *POJO*:

```java
public class Address {

    private Integer m_id;
    private String m_city;

    public Address(Integer id, String city) {
        m_city = city;
        m_id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return m_id;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return m_city;
    }
}
```

The result will be (generated *PDF* file):

[image: The generated report in *PDF* format]

In the sample I've used a *Java bean* based datasource, but this method is also works for *jdbc* datasource.

---

You can easy reverse sorting by replacing sort option (change the value of ***order*** property from **Ascending** to **Descending**):

```xml
<sortField name="isNull" order="Descending" type="Variable"/>
```

this expression will sort data for showing null and empty values in the top of list.